# MYSQL Query most recent entry

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Here is the problem. I need to transform this query to get the right information and Im not sure how.

Database info

```
   Id    |   Client_Code   |  Time_Date          | Employee_Name | Date_Time | Time_Stamp  
    1    |    000010       |  2010-11-17 07:45:00| Jerry         | 2010-11-17| 07:45 AM
    2    |    000022       |  2010-11-17 07:30:00| Jerry         | 2010-11-17| 07:30 AM
    3    |    000010       |  2010-11-17 16:00:00| Bill          | 2010-11-17| 04:00 PM
    4    |    000022       |  2010-11-17 16:00:00| Bill          | 2010-11-17| 04:00 PM
```

Here is the query

```
$sql = "SELECT Client_Code, MAX(TIME(Time_Date)), Employee_Name, Date_Time, Time_Stamp FROM Transaction WHERE Date_Time = CURdate()
                    AND Time_Stamp != '' GROUP BY Client_Code";
```

Here is what i get with this query and phpcode

```
echo " $row[Employee_Name], $row[Client_Code], ".$row['MAX(TIME(Time_Date))']."<br>";
Jerry, 000010, 16:00:00
Bill, 000022, 16:00:00
```

For some reason yes its giving me the right 16:00:00 Time but it is not giving me the right employee name with that time. It has something to do with the grouping I think but the group has to be by client_code first because I want the most recent entry for each Client_Code. Also I can not use ID for grouping because inputs are not always in order. Here is what is should look like.

```
Bill, 000010, 16:00:00
Bill, 000022, 16:00:00
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this query to get the correct information please. Also once the mysql query is corrected Ill need it to count each employee up and display the results like so.

```
Bill, 2
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: Aren't the date values duplicated??

Comment: If you append to the query ORDER BY MAX(TIME(Time_Date)) what does that do?

Comment: I want the most recent entry for each Client_Code. Displaying Employee_Name, Client_Code, and time. Then once I get a query that does that I need to add count to that query to get the final Employee_Name, in this case a count of 2

Comment: Same results if i append that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a self join:

```
SELECT x.client_code,
       TIME(x.time_date)
       x.employee_name,
       x.date_time,
       x.time_stamp
  FROM TRANSACTION x
  JOIN (SELECT t.client_code,
               MAX(t.time_date) AS max_time_date
          FROM TRANSACTION t
         WHERE t.date_time = CURRENT_DATE
           AND t.time_stamp != ''
      GROUP BY t.client_code) y ON y.client_code = x.client_code
                               AND y.max_time_date = x.time_date
 WHERE x.date_time = CURRENT_DATE
   AND x.time_stamp != ''
```

Comment: How would I add a Count to this so I get the count for each employee?

Comment: Take that existing query and surround it with:  SELECT employee_name, count(*) FROM (query from above) A

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "order by id desc limit 0,1" to your query or you can try to mysql_last_insert_id

Comment: Someone at anytime can enter new data behind the most recent time giving it a higher ID number then the actual most recent time entry. That wont work either. Wished it was that easy.